# Django requirements.txt FIle in root

Tags: python, django

I have set-up a requirements folder as such:

```
requirements/
  local.txt
  development.txt/
  production.txt/
```

I am wondering what I put in my base requirements.txt file to redirect to the appropriate file? I don't want to have to use the `-r requirements/local.txt`. I want a solution based off my virtual environment.

Is there a similar variable to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` except for requirements instead of settings?

Comment: Shouldn't the requirements for dev and production always be equal? Sounds like a very poor idea to be using different requirements.

Comment: @oneloop not necessarily, this is an elegant way to maintain diffrent evns, there is no reason for test packages to be in production, if you were using nose or another testing package

Comment: @oneloop development.txt contains modules only used for development, like tools for debugging,profiling and writing docs ...or modules you used to develop new features thus you will not pollute the production.txt

Comment: In an app that has a `Django` backend and `Angular` frontend, should the `requirements.txt` file be in the root directory (and run there with `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt`) or should it be in the backend folder where files such as `manage.py` are located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

generally there is a some sort of
`common.txt` requirments file which would hold the shared packages, like `django` and you could extend that in your `development.txt` with a line that says

```
-r requirements/common.txt
pygraphviz
django-nose
```

etc..

The above imitates a sort of inheritance, and is a common and elegant (i believe) way to handle multiple requirments

I am pretty sure there is not a solution that allows you to set an environmental variable that points to a requirements file, and have the webserver automaticaly bootstrap your environment with the packages listed in the file; although that would be pretty cool if there were!

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in environment variable pip will use to locate the requirements.txt. But you can define your own.

e.g

export PIP_REQUIREMENTS_TXT=requirements/development.txt

pip install -r $PIP_REQUIREMENTS_TXT